# Impala has his own execution engine or it works on MapR in Hadoop eco system?

Tags: mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop2, impala

I never got a chance to work on Impala. I have just started reading about Impala. But i have one basic question which i am not clear about Impala. Impala has its own demons so it also has its own execution engine or it works on MapR or other execution engine.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Added details around your query. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MapReduce` is a design pattern for processing large data sets in a distributed and parallel mode.

`Impala` is an open source Massively Parallel Processing (MPP) query engine that runs on Apache Hadoop. `Impala` is more of a warehouse like `Hive` with its own pro-cons vs `Hive`.

**Major differences between `Imapala` and `mapreduce` are:**

- `Impala` does not use `mapreduce`. It runs separate `Impala daemon` which splits the query and runs them in parallel and merge result set at the end.
- `Impala` does most of its operation in-memory and disk I/O is limited.
- `Impala` uses `hdfs` for its storage which brings in reliability with efficiency.  It caches in-memory as much as possible results from queries.
- `Impala` supports new file format like `parquet`, which is columnar file format. So if you use this format it will be faster for queries where you are accessing only few columns most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Impala daemons runs the SQL in memory with the resident pool of resources available and managed by YARN or any other resource scheduler. This can be tweaked.

MapR is a hadoop distribution package - and yes it does offer Impala as part of larger bundle.